# Node.js with puppeteer Run only one instance per txt file line

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

can you help me to run puppeteer one by one with the ${line} value from txt file.

I want the Node to run 1st (or limit it to 2-3) instance of browser, get data from the site, close it, wait(15000), and proceed to the next line from the accounts.txt

Here is my current code:

````
process.setMaxListeners(Infinity);
const lineReader = require('line-reader');
var fs = require('fs')

var Date = `2022-10-12`


lineReader.eachLine('accounts.txt', function(line, last) {
  console.log(line);
  var url = `https://mining.alienworlds.tools/?account=${line}&date=${Date}&skip=0`;
      puppeteer.launch({
       headless:true,
       args: [`--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36`]
      })
      .then(async browser => {
        const waitFor = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
        await waitFor(1000);
        var page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 500 });
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        const element = await page.waitForSelector("#__layout > div > div > div > div.row > div.col-lg-6.col-account > div > div:nth-child(3) > div"); 
        const value = await element.evaluate(el => el.textContent); // grab the textContent from the element,
        console.log(line,` - `, value);
        await browser.close();
if(last){
}
})})```
````

Comment: ...why? What value does "closing the browser" add over just opening a new URL in the same browser instance? What are you actually doing that made you decide to use puppeteer for this job? (to prevent an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/395686))

Comment: I'm using puppeteer because in somehow familiar with it but its not a need. The site i'm taking data from have some kind of cooldown between the calls and when i run async puppeteer i get data only from about 5 lines and rest returns. So i want to include those cooldown between calls

Comment: But to do _what_? Because it looks like you're just getting a value out of the URL's response source code, in which case why use puppetteer at all when node can already pretty trivially fetch URLs using `node-fetch` (or less trivially, but still very easily, using the http or https module) and turn them into a DOM you can query using `jsdom`. No puppeteer or browsers required.